# Save Images from MimeMessage C# MailKit

Tags: c#, mailkit

I wrote a method that saves all the images from the email. The problem is that it doesn't save images that are contained in div containers. How can this be fixed using MailKit (without installing additional nuget packages)?

This method adds the images from the message to the attachments list. But it ignores the images in the div. I would be very grateful for help. Thank you very much in advance!

```
private void AttachPicturesFromMessage(MimeMessage message, List<EMailMessageAttachment> attachments)
{
    var counter = 1;
    foreach (MimePart att in message.BodyParts)
    {
        if (att.ContentId != null && att.ContentObject != null
                && att.ContentType.MediaType == "image")
        {
            byte[] byteCode;
            using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
            {
                att.ContentObject.DecodeTo(mem);
                byteCode = mem.ToArray();
            }
            attachments.Add(new EMailMessageAttachment { 
                FileName = $"{message.Subject}_{counter}.jpg",
                Content = byteCode }); 
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for the suggested way, jstedfast! Before your answer, I solved the problem this way:

```
private void AttachImagesFromMessage(MimeMessage message, List<EMailMessageAttachment> attachments)
    {
        var imageCounter = 1;
        AttachImagesFromBody(message, attachments, ref imageCounter);
        AttachImagesFromDiv(message, attachments, ref imageCounter);
    }

    private void AttachImagesFromBody(MimeMessage message,
        List<EMailMessageAttachment> attachments, ref int imageCounter)
    {
        // Processing embedded images in the message body
        foreach (MimePart image in message.BodyParts)
        {
            if (image.ContentId != null && image.ContentObject != null && image.ContentType.MediaType == "image")
            {
                byte[] byteCode;
                using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.ContentObject.DecodeTo(mem);
                    byteCode = mem.ToArray();
                }
                attachments.Add(new EMailMessageAttachment
                {
                    FileName = $"Image_{imageCounter}.jpg",
                    Content = byteCode
                });
                imageCounter++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void AttachImagesFromDiv(MimeMessage message,
        List<EMailMessageAttachment> attachments, ref int imageCounter)
    {
        var htmlBody = message.HtmlBody;
        if (htmlBody != null)
        {
            // Search for div tags containing images
            var regex = new Regex("<div[^>]*>.*?<img[^>]*src=\"(.*?)\".*?>.*?</div>",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
            var matchCollection = regex.Matches(htmlBody);

            // Extracting images and adding them to the attachments collection
            foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
            {
                var imageUrl = match.Groups[1].Value;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageUrl) && imageUrl.StartsWith("http"))
                {
                    var imageBytes = DownloadImage(imageUrl);
                    if (imageBytes != null)
                    {
                        attachments.Add(new EMailMessageAttachment
                        {
                            FileName = $"Image_{imageCounter}.jpg",
                            Content = imageBytes
                        });
                        imageCounter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private byte[] DownloadImage(string imageUrl)
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                return webClient.DownloadData(imageUrl);
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Failed to load the image from the link {imageUrl}. {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
```

It looks bulky and ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using will only save images that are actually attached to the message but it sounds like what you want to do is save images that the browser control renders after downloading them from a web server via an HTML image tag.

MimeKit *does* have an HTML tokenizer in the MimeKit.Text namespace that *can* be used for this kind of task, but it's a pretty low-level API. The way you'd use it would be something like this (untested code follows):

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
    var html = message.HtmlBody;
    using (var reader = new StringReader(html)) {
        var tokenizer = new HtmlTokenizer(reader);
    
        while (tokenizer.ReadNext(out var token)) {
            if (token is HtmlTokenTag tag && tag.Id == HtmlTagId.Image &&
                tag.Attributes.TryGetValue("src", out var src)) {
    
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(src.Value);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var imageStream = await response.Content.GetAsStreamAsync();
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're exactly correct.  To elaborate: the OP needs to understand a) an email has multiple "parts". Which include "MIME attachments". b) His code is reading only the "attachments". c) Image attachments *ARE ENCODED DIRECTLY IN THE EMAIL*. d) "<div>" elements need to be parsed from the HTML. e) Any image referenced in a "<div>" needs to be downloaded separately, from the web server.